How can I use Gradio API?
In "https://huggingface.co/spaces/Vision-CAIR/MiniGPT-v2#/", from this Use via API documentation, I don't know what its input is. I tried many times but failed.I don't know how to call Gradio's API.
For example,in the picture，what do “# str representing string value in 'parameter_0' Textbox component in the figure” and “# str representing filepath to JSON file in 'MiniGPT-v2' Chatbot component” mean？gradio api example
Now I have encountered a new problem.When I enter "client = Client("https://vision-cair-minigpt-v2.hf.space/")", the problemConnectionError shown in the picture appears.
